# Help with Linked list functions....overloaded stream op and get and set functions C++

Tags: c++, get, operator-overloading, linked-list, set

Hey everyone, I'm kind of stuck right now, need help with overloading the stream op in these classes.  Also need help with access data in the linked list I am creating, In the throwMudAt() function I need to find distance but do not know how to call the individual variables of the node. (each node has an x and a Y and i need to find the distance between any given node and a point (x,y) passed to it.
Thanks!
Missing anything point me in the right direction please.

```
class Linknode {
  friend class SchmooList;
 public:
  Linknode(){next=0; data =0;}
  ~Linknode(){if (data){delete data; data =0;}}

 private:
  Linknode *next; //"SRO"
  Schmoo *data;

};
#endif
```

---

```
class SchmooList {
 public:
  SchmooList(){first=0;}
  // ~SchmooList();
  bool isEmpty(){return first==NULL;}
  void insertFront(Schmoo*);
  void throwMudAt(double, double);//throws mud at the given (x,y) and adds one
                             //to the mud value of any schmoo within 5.0 feet of given
                             //within 5.0 means distance <= to 5.0
  void removeAt(double, double); //removes any Schmoo that is within 1.0 feet
  int getPopulation();
  void printAll();//send each Schmoo to STDOUT one per line in list order


 private:
  Linknode *first;


};
#endif
```

---

```
using namespace std;

void SchmooList::insertFront(Schmoo *nt){
  Linknode *temp= new Linknode();
  temp -> data=nt;
  temp->next=first;
  first = temp;

}
void SchmooList::throwMudAt(double xx, double yy){
  Linknode *temp=first;
  while(temp){
    double sum = (pow(xx - temp->data.getX(), 2))+(pow(yy - temp->data.getX(), 2));
    double distance = sgrt(sum);

}

/*void SchmooList::removeAt(double x, double y){
   Linknode *temp=first
      while(temp){
       double xd=
       double yd= temp - y;
        if(xd <= 1 || yd <= 1){
         temp == 0;

*/

int SchmooList::getPopulation(){
  int pop=0;
  Linknode *temp=first;
  while(temp){
    pop++;
    temp=temp->next;
  }
  return pop;

}

void SchmooList::printAll(){

  Linknode *temp=first;
  while(temp){
    cout << '*' << endl;      //print the object

    temp = temp->next;
  }
  cout << getPopulation();//for testing
}
```

---

```
class Schmoo{


 public:
  Schmoo(double, double);
  void setX(double);
  double getX() const;
  void setY(double);
  double getY() const;
  void setMud(int);
  int getMud() const;


 private:
  double x;
  double y;
  int mud;

};
#endif
```

---

```
Schmoo::Schmoo(double xx, double yy){
  x = xx;
  y = yy;
  setMud(0);

}


void Schmoo::setX(double x1){
  x = ( x1 >= -1000 && x1 <= 1000) ? x1 : 0;

}
double Schmoo::getX() const{
  return x;

}
void Schmoo::setMud(int m){
  mud = ( m >= -1000 && m <= 1000) ? m : 0;
}
int Schmoo::getMud() const{
  return mud;
}
/*ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, Schmoo &s){
  if(s->getMud() == 1){
    os << "Schmoo at (" << s.x << ", " << s.y << ") was hit mud " << mud << "time.";
  }
  os << "Schmoo at (" << s.x << ", " << s.y << ") was hit with mud" << mud << "times.";
  return os;
}
*/
```

Comment: People are more likely to answer your questions if they don't have to read through so much code. Try to make a compilable example that illustrates your problem, but is as simple as possible. That'll make it easier for us to help you solve it?

Comment: i thought having all the code would help. in paticular...
I am looking for help on the throw mud at, i explained its purpose in the initial post... but where i am having problems is how to use a variable from one of the nodes. like here i am trying to access the X and Y variables from a node...

void SchmooList::throwMudAt(double xx, double yy){
  Linknode *temp=first;
  while(temp){
    double sum = (pow(xx - temp->data.getX(), 2))+(pow(yy - temp->data.getX(), 2));
    double distance = sgrt(sum);

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to go forward in your list.

```
  void SchmooList::throwMudAt(double xx, double yy){
      Linknode *temp=first;
      while(temp){
        double sum = (pow(xx - temp->data.getX(), 2))+(pow(yy - temp->data.getX(), 2));
        double distance = sqrt(sum);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
```

Comment: that function was incomplete. but i figured it out...
any help with the << operator overloading would be nice...
i need to figure out how to call the getX() functions etc. from that function.

Comment: I don't get it, what do you mean when you say help with "How to call getX()"? It's the same as any other function as far as I know, unless I'm missing something, please explain.